# Verb with conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

What sounds more natural , especially what kind of usage of verbs :

" I will come to you if  I don't be held up at work" or
" I will come to you if I am not held up at work"

Thanks

Comment: *BE* always acts like an auxiliary verb, even when it is the main verb in a clause, so it does not take *do* support: "...if I *am* not held up..."

Comment: **"I will come to you if I am not held up at work"** This sounds way more natural

Comment: Don't be too certain, @StoneyB.  "Always" is a strong word.  I'm pretty sure we can find a counter-example.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Aptly expressed!

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan, StoneyB. As it goes conditionals are one environment where we sometimes see lexical as opposed to auxiliary BE "If you don't be careful, you're going to have an accident", for example. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem itself is not actually 'verb with the conditional clause' in my opinion. It is the way passive voice is formed.
Your second sentence is more natural and, if I get it right, it's also the only grammatically correct solution of two.

> I will come to you if I am not **held** up at work.

In the sentence above, you used a **passive voice** with the main verb `hold`. And it **requires** the auxiliary verb `be`.

With other ordinary verbs, yes, you can use the negative verb `do` with `not` to form a complete main verb. With `be`... no. On the other hand, your first sentence can sound better if [get](http://www.esl-lounge.com/student/grammar/3g3-get-passive.php) is used: `I will come to you if I don't get held up at work.`

More information about passive and active voice [here](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/activepass.htm).